# Как сделать блоки в ряд слева направо, но по центру

Tags: html, css, float

Здравствуйте!

Как сделать в "HTML" блоки в ряд слева направо, но по центру!
Мне надо 3 блока разместить горизонтально в одну линию. При изменении разрешения экрана, например на мобильных устройствах, блоки могут размещаться вертикально, но по центру.

```css
.outline-3 {
    width: 32%; /* Ширина слоя */ 
    max-width: 32%; /* Максимальная Ширина слоя */ 
    min-width: 370px;/* Минимальная ширина слоя */ 
 /* float: left;  Выравнивание блока слева */ 
 background: #E6EEDE; /* Цвет фона */
 box-shadow: 7px 7px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6), /* Наружняя тень */
             0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) inset, /* Наружняя вертикальная тень */
    0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset; /* Внутренняя тень */
 border: 1px solid #000000; /* Рамка */
 border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px; /* Отступы */
   }

.text-2 {    
 font: 18pt tahoma;
 color: #1E293B;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Тень текста*/
   }
```

```html
<div class="outline-3" align="center">
   <p class="text-2">Если ты хочешь получать свежие подробные статьи этого блога
                     с картинками и видео в свой почтовый ящик, то введи свой E-mail 
      в форму ниже, и как только я напишу статью на блоге, 
      ты первым об этом узнаешь!
 </p> 
      
  </div>
  
  <div class="outline-3" align="center">
   <p class="text-2">Если ты хочешь получать свежие подробные статьи этого блога
                     с картинками и видео в свой почтовый ящик, то введи свой E-mail 
      в форму ниже, и как только я напишу статью на блоге, 
      ты первым об этом узнаешь!
 </p> 
      
  </div>
  
  <div class="outline-3" align="center">
   <p class="text-2">Если ты хочешь получать свежие подробные статьи этого блога
                     с картинками и видео в свой почтовый ящик, то введи свой E-mail 
      в форму ниже, и как только я напишу статью на блоге, 
      ты первым об этом узнаешь!
 </p> 

  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например с помощью свойства `display: inline-block;` :

```css
.outline-3 {
    width: 32%; /* Ширина слоя */ 
    max-width: 32%; /* Максимальная Ширина слоя */ 
    min-width: 370px;/* Минимальная ширина слоя */ 
 /* float: left;  Выравнивание блока слева */ 
 background: #E6EEDE; /* Цвет фона */
 box-shadow: 7px 7px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6), /* Наружняя тень */
             0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) inset, /* Наружняя вертикальная тень */
    0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset; /* Внутренняя тень */
 border: 1px solid #000000; /* Рамка */
 border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px; /* Отступы */
  
  text-align: center; /* Выравнивание содержимого по-центру */
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.text-2 {    
 font: 18pt tahoma;
 color: #1E293B;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Тень текста*/
}

.wrap {
  text-align: center; /* Задает контенту выравнивание по-центру */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="outline-3">
   <p class="text-2">Если ты хочешь получать свежие подробные статьи этого блога
                     с картинками и видео в свой почтовый ящик, то введи свой E-mail 
      в форму ниже, и как только я напишу статью на блоге, 
      ты первым об этом узнаешь!
 </p> 
      
  </div>
  
  <div class="outline-3" >
   <p class="text-2">Если ты хочешь получать свежие подробные статьи этого блога
                     с картинками и видео в свой почтовый ящик, то введи свой E-mail 
      в форму ниже, и как только я напишу статью на блоге, 
      ты первым об этом узнаешь!
 </p> 
      
  </div>
  
  <div class="outline-3" >
   <p class="text-2">Если ты хочешь получать свежие подробные статьи этого блога
                     с картинками и видео в свой почтовый ящик, то введи свой E-mail 
      в форму ниже, и как только я напишу статью на блоге, 
      ты первым об этом узнаешь!
 </p> 

  </div> 
</div>
```

Либо так, с помощью свойства `flex`:

```css
.outline-3 {
    width: 32%; /* Ширина слоя */ 
    max-width: 32%; /* Максимальная Ширина слоя */ 
    min-width: 370px;/* Минимальная ширина слоя */ 
 /* float: left;  Выравнивание блока слева */ 
 background: #E6EEDE; /* Цвет фона */
 box-shadow: 7px 7px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6), /* Наружняя тень */
             0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) inset, /* Наружняя вертикальная тень */
    0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset; /* Внутренняя тень */
 border: 1px solid #000000; /* Рамка */
 border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px; /* Отступы */
  
  text-align: center; /* Выравнивание содержимого по-центру */
}

.text-2 {    
 font: 18pt tahoma;
 color: #1E293B;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Тень текста*/
}

.wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="outline-3">
   <p class="text-2">Если ты хочешь получать свежие подробные статьи этого блога
                     с картинками и видео в свой почтовый ящик, то введи свой E-mail 
      в форму ниже, и как только я напишу статью на блоге, 
      ты первым об этом узнаешь!
 </p> 
      
  </div>
  
  <div class="outline-3" >
   <p class="text-2">Если ты хочешь получать свежие подробные статьи этого блога
                     с картинками и видео в свой почтовый ящик, то введи свой E-mail 
      в форму ниже, и как только я напишу статью на блоге, 
      ты первым об этом узнаешь!
 </p> 
      
  </div>
  
  <div class="outline-3" >
   <p class="text-2">Если ты хочешь получать свежие подробные статьи этого блога
                     с картинками и видео в свой почтовый ящик, то введи свой E-mail 
      в форму ниже, и как только я напишу статью на блоге, 
      ты первым об этом узнаешь!
 </p> 

  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! А как сделать, что если на маленьком разрешении 1 блок сместился вниз , то все блоки расположить вертикально? Просто мне нужно чтобы блоки размещались в ряд либо горизонтально, либо вертикально, но например не 2 блока горизонтально, а 3 сьехал вниз...

Comment: @МаратНаурузбаев, с `display: inline-block;` - при меньшем разрешении, точно будут перестраиваться друг под другом и по-центру, а в случае с flex, код для `.wrap` лучше оформить так:`flex-flow: row wrap;` - это позволит блокам перестраиваться, если не будут влазить.

Comment: Не перестраиваются http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//free-pc.ru/podpiska/&w=1024&h=600&a=1&s=1

Comment: http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//free-pc.ru/podpiska/&w=768&h=1024&a=22&s=1

Answer (score 0):

```css
.content { /* родительский div */
  text-align: center;  /* выравнивание блочных елементов по центру */
  }

.outline-3 {
    width: 100px; /* Ширину изменил на фиксированую для наглядности */ 
    
  
 background: #E6EEDE; /* Цвет фона */
 box-shadow: 7px 7px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6), /* Наружняя тень */
             0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) inset, /* Наружняя вертикальная тень */
    0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset; /* Внутренняя тень */
 border: 1px solid #000000; /* Рамка */
 border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px; /* Отступы */
  
  
  
  text-align: center; /* выравнивание по центру */
  display: inline-block; /* делаем div-ы блоками */
   }

.text-2 {    
 font: 18pt tahoma;
 color: #1E293B;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Тень текста*/
   }
```

```html
<div class="content" >
<div class="outline-3" >
   <p class="text-2">Если ты хочешь получать свежие подробные статьи этого блога
                     с картинками и видео в свой почтовый ящик, то введи свой E-mail 
      в форму ниже, и как только я напишу статью на блоге, 
      ты первым об этом узнаешь!
 </p> 
      
  </div>
  
  <div class="outline-3" align="center">
   <p class="text-2">Если ты хочешь получать свежие подробные статьи этого блога
                     с картинками и видео в свой почтовый ящик, то введи свой E-mail 
      в форму ниже, и как только я напишу статью на блоге, 
      ты первым об этом узнаешь!
 </p> 
      
  </div>
  
  <div class="outline-3" align="center">
   <p class="text-2">Если ты хочешь получать свежие подробные статьи этого блога
                     с картинками и видео в свой почтовый ящик, то введи свой E-mail 
      в форму ниже, и как только я напишу статью на блоге, 
      ты первым об этом узнаешь!
 </p> 

  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Все предельно просто. Вот готовый код. Блоки стоят в одну линию по середине. При изменении ширины экрана, блоки уходят в низ, но они остаются по центру.

```css
.content {
  text-align: center;
  display:inline-block;
  }

.outline-3 {
   display:inline-block;
    width: 32%;
    max-width: 32%;
    min-width: 370px;
 background: #E6EEDE;
 box-shadow: 7px 7px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6),
             0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) inset, 
    0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
   }

.text-2 {    
 font: 18pt tahoma;
 color: #1E293B;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.9); 
   }
```

```html
<div class="content" >
<div class="outline-3" >
   <p class="text-2">Если ты хочешь получать свежие подробные статьи этого блога
                     с картинками и видео в свой почтовый ящик, то введи свой E-mail 
      в форму ниже, и как только я напишу статью на блоге, 
      ты первым об этом узнаешь!
 </p> 
      
  </div>
  
  <div class="outline-3">
   <p class="text-2">Если ты хочешь получать свежие подробные статьи этого блога
                     с картинками и видео в свой почтовый ящик, то введи свой E-mail 
      в форму ниже, и как только я напишу статью на блоге, 
      ты первым об этом узнаешь!
 </p> 
      
  </div>
  
  <div class="outline-3">
   <p class="text-2">Если ты хочешь получать свежие подробные статьи этого блога
                     с картинками и видео в свой почтовый ящик, то введи свой E-mail 
      в форму ниже, и как только я напишу статью на блоге, 
      ты первым об этом узнаешь!
 </p> 

  </div>
  </div>
```